# Rails ActionCable Invalid frame header on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx, puma, actioncable

I have an actioncable application,  on development it works fine, but when and deploy to production on Amazon Web Service. I have this problem

**WebSocket connection to 'ws://www.mydomain.com/cable' failed: Invalid frame header**

My nginx configuration file

```
upstream my_app {
    server unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock;
  }
  server {
   listen 80;
   server_name www.mydomain.com;

   access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
   error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
   root /var/app/current/public;

   location / {
    try_files $uri @ruby;
   }

   location @ruby {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://my_app;
   }

   location /cable {
    proxy_pass http://my_app;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
   }
  }
```

Cable.yml

`development:
      adapter: redis
    test:
      adapter: redis
    production:
      adapter: redis
      url: <%= ENV['REDIS_URL'] %>`

enviroments/production.eb

```
config.action_cable.url = 'ws://www.mydomain.com/cable'
```

Please if someone can help me

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but my production.rb has this `config.action_cable.url = "wss://#{ENV['RAILS_HOST']}/cable"`  Also - I'm sure you've seen this? https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp/issues/120

Comment: thanks, but not working =(

Comment: @JuanCarlosGamezLozano were you able to figure out the solution ?